# Spark Thrift beeline: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset

Tags: apache-spark, beeline, hdp

I started Spark Thrift Server within HDP 3.1.

I tried to connect to it via beeline:
`beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://myhost.mybank.rus:10016/public"`

And I got error:

`19/10/10 00:17:08 [main]: ERROR jdbc.HiveConnection: Error opening session
    org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null, configuration:{set:hiveconf:
            at
...`

I found only that it need's hive/beeline jar's older version, but how to configure it?

Answer (score 5):

Spend few hours to find answer.
Nobody sais than Spark has it's own beeline tool:

`/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/spark2/bin/beeline`

And it works :)

Comment: Yes it works with the spark beeline ! Thanks @Pavel